# How to resize a div's max-height upon window resize?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been searching high and low for an answer. I have read through some things on here and no one seems to have a solution to what I am wanting to do. I am wanting to resize a div's max-height when the window size reaches a certain point. The main menu is at the bottom of the page and the content comes out of the menu sliding upwards.

Example of what I have:

```
<div class="content">
    //some content pics/text etc.
</div>
```

css:

```
.content { width: 550px; overflow: auto; }`
```

Now obviously I can set the max-height in the css currently but I don't need it to take effect until the screen size reaches 800px in height. Let me know if I am missing something simple here.

I am open to using jQuery or css rules.

Comment: So basically when the screen reaches 800px or less you want to set a `max-height` style and else you don't want it to have a `max-height`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if($(this).height() <= 800){
        $('.content').css('max-height', '800px'); //set max height
    }else{
        $('.content').css('max-height', ''); //delete attribute
    }
});
```

Comment: hey if you're still looking at this could I ask one quick question about jQuery and max-height not working with each other

Comment: I am using a jQuery scrollbar.  When I use the max-height property on my div.content it removes the jquery scrollbar and replaces it with a normal one.  When I remove the max-height is uses the jquery scrollbar.

Comment: I meant a different question... Your previous answer was spot on for the other problem I was having.  I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

I have an example: http://jsfiddle.net/sechou/WwpuJ/

```
$(window).resize(function () { 
   if($(window).height() <= 800){
       $('div.content').css('max-height', 800);
   }else{
       $('div.content').css('max-height', ''); 
   }  
});
```

Comment: This is a great example.  I would have made this my accepted answer if it would have resized to the original. +1 tho

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an oldish post but I wonder if a CSS only solution would have been (and would now be) better here?

```
.content {
    // No need for max-height here
}

@media(max-height:800px){
    .content {
        max-height:800px;
    }
}
```