# set the maximum height among the divs and set height on window resize

Tags: jquery

I have tried this but its not working on

```
$(window).resize(function () {

    var maxHeight = -1;

    $('.front-block .item-title').each(function () {

        maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).outerHeight() ? maxHeight : $(this).outerHeight();

    });

    $('.front-block .item-title').each(function () {

        $(this).height(maxHeight);

    });
});
```

Comment: Define not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize a div's max-height upon window resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981174/how-to-resize-a-divs-max-height-upon-window-resize)

Comment: You'll have to show an example, much will likely depend on the styling for your `.front-block .item-title`'s and such. can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: Maybe this can help you too https://stackoverflow.com/a/2758657/5626568

Comment: This also https://stackoverflow.com/a/11995705/5626568